# Make disabled text render black

Tags: wxpython

I have a window that is always on top as a status display. The problem is that when it is not the focused window the text (using wx.StaticText) becomes gray and thus harder to read.

Is it possible to make the text render in black even though the window is not focused?

Comment: So far I have fixed this by reimplementing wx.StaticText in the same way as it is defined in the wxpython source tree except to change the disabled color.

Comment: You should be able to write your own Enable function, (based on the source for wx.StaticText), and override that function only in a derived class.

Comment: @SteveBarnes If you add an answer with this then I'll accept it.

Comment: It turns out that creating your own Enable function works on Windows and linux but not on Mac.

Comment: Another reason for me not to like Mac!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created my own label widget that doesn't render as gray when disabled. It's unfortunate to have to do this since there is a lot of boilerplate to creating your own widget. In case anybody wants to solve the same problem, here is the code for the widget:

```
class MyStaticText(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="", 
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, 
                 style=0, validator=wx.DefaultValidator, 
                 name="MyStaticText"):
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style|wx.NO_BORDER,
                              validator, name)
        wx.PyControl.SetLabel(self, label)
        self.InheritAttributes()
        self.SetInitialSize(size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        self.Draw(dc)

    def Draw(self, dc):
        width, height = self.GetClientSize()

        if not width or not height:
            return

        backBrush = wx.Brush(wx.WHITE, wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetBackground(backBrush)
        dc.Clear()

        dc.SetTextForeground(wx.BLACK)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        label = self.GetLabel()
        dc.DrawText(label, 0, 0)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass

    def SetLabel(self, label):
        wx.PyControl.SetLabel(self, label)
        self.InvalidateBestSize()
        self.SetSize(self.GetBestSize())
        self.Refresh()

    def SetFont(self, font):
        wx.PyControl.SetFont(self, font)
        self.InvalidateBestSize()
        self.SetSize(self.GetBestSize())
        self.Refresh()

    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        label = self.GetLabel()
        font = self.GetFont()

        if not font:
            font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)

        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.SetFont(font)

        textWidth, textHeight = dc.GetTextExtent(label)
        best = wx.Size(textWidth, textHeight)
        self.CacheBestSize(best)
        return best

    def AcceptsFocus(self):
        return False

    def SetForegroundColour(self, colour):
        wx.PyControl.SetForegroundColour(self, colour)
        self.Refresh()

    def SetBackgroundColour(self, colour):
        wx.PyControl.SetBackgroundColour(self, colour)
        self.Refresh()

    def GetDefaultAttributes(self):
        return wx.StaticText.GetClassDefaultAttributes()

    def ShouldInheritColours(self):
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the background colour to make the grey clearer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But ideally I'd like no change in the text color.